# boost spirit x3 variant Recursive assignment problem

Tags: c++, recursive-datastructures, boost-variant, boost-spirit-x3

In special scenarios

I have this data structure

```
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
struct one;
struct two : x3::variant<x3::forward_ast<one>,int>{
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
    two& operator=(const std::string& rhs){
        return *this;
    }
    two& operator=(const std::string&& rhs){
        return *this;
    }
};
struct one :  x3::variant<boost::recursive_wrapper<two>,std::string>{
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};
```

In this case, the assignment is OK

```
one  on{"sssss"};
two  wo{22};
wo = 123;
on = std::string("vvvvvvvvvvv");
on = wo;
```

But when I directly assign a string to wo, it prompts an error：

```
wo = on;
// wo = one("sadfasdfas"); //You can't do this
wo = std::string("sadfasdfas"); <----【/usr/local/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:2172:14: Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' to 'boost::variant<boost::spirit::x3::forward_ast<one>, int>' for 1st argument】
```

I have overloaded the relevant functions, but it seems to have no effect。
Who knows why this is and tell me how to make the correct modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you overloaded `two::operator=` for `const std::string&` and `const std::string&&`, neither of which is the best match for overload resolution with (non-const) rvalue argument `std::string("vvvvvvvvvvv")`. Instead, the best match comes from `x3::variant::operator=(T&&)` ([source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp)) which you included with `using base_type::operator=`:

```
 template <typename T, class = non_self_t<T>>
 variant& operator=(T&& rhs) BOOST_NOEXCEPT_IF((std::is_nothrow_assignable<variant_type, T&&>::value))
 {
     var = std::forward<T>(rhs);
     return *this;
 }
```

The line `var = std::forward<T>(rhs);` results in compilation error you mentioned (`var` is `boost::variant<boost::spirit::x3::forward_ast<one>, int>` to which a string cannot be assigned).

To make your overloads work as intended you can just make your rvalue assignment operator accept non-const rvalue reference to make it higher priority in overload resolution than templated `operator=` (and to actually make it possible to adequately implement, because you wouldn't be able to move from `const std::string&&` anyway):

```
two& operator=(std::string&& rhs) {
    return *this;
}
```

([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qaY3o5v1M))

Note that you don't need to 'break inheritance cycle' second time in `one` by `boost::recursive_wrapper`, it can be removed. Also, `// wo = one("sadfasdfas");` can be uncommented and work as intended as well.